# Edit encrypted, compressed files fails

Tags: org-mode, encryption, epa, archive-mode, compression

I've been trying to write an encrypted org document which also has images. A requirement is that the images should be bundled with the org document.

I thought that the most straightforward approach would be to bundle the document, alongside all the pictures, in a tar archive, and encrypt that, obtaining, in the end, a document.tar.gpg containing a single document.org and lots of images.

The workflow I aimed at was that I could open document.tar.gpg/document.org, relying on Emacs' transparent handling of encrypted files as regular files (doing the encryption/decryption on the fly) and archives as directories. I also hoped that, by putting relative paths to the images in the org document, when I tried to open them in Emacs it could work even if the images are actually in an encrypted archive.

Unfortunately, it seems that encrypted archives make something in that stack not behave as it should, and in the end I just couldn't edit a compressed archive. At the creation of the archive, it works as expected, tar-mode allows me to navigate the archive as if it wasn't encrypted. However, when I save, close the buffer, and open that file again, after showing me it tells me `File mode specification error: (error Malformed Tar header)`. It shows me the content of the archive, but tar-mode fails to launch properly, and nothing works anymore.

How can I edit an encrypted archive in Emacs, in a transparent fashion (ie. without decrypting it first)?